# MySQL Join Scenario

Tags: mysql, join

I know there are many "similar" questions, but I cannot figure out how to make this work. I am hoping it is quite simple for someone else!

I have a query that looks like the following:

```
SELECT
    d.name DishName,
    alt.name AllergyName
FROM meals_dish d
JOIN meals_dishingredient di ON di.dish_id = d.id
LEFT JOIN meals_food_allergytypes fat ON fat.food_id = di.food_id
LEFT JOIN meals_allergytypes alt ON alt.id = fat.allergytypes_id
GROUP BY d.id, alt.id
ORDER BY d.name
```

that is giving me table similar to the following:

```
Dish Name               |    AllergyName
-----------------------------------------
Almond Pudding          |     NULL
Almond Pudding          |     Egg
Apple Cake              |     Milk
Apple Cake              |     Lactose
Apple Cake              |     Egg
Apple Cake              |     NULL
Avocado Chocolate Cream |     Milk
Avocado Chocolate Cream |     Lactose
Avocado Chocolate Cream |     NULL
Avocado Chocolate Cream |     Peanuts
Avocado Chocolate Cream |     Tree Nuts
Avocado Chocolate Cream |     Soy
Avocado Egg             |     NULL
Avocado Egg             |     Egg
Bacon Wrapped Asparagus |     NULL
Baked Cauliflower       |     NULL
Baked Cauliflower       |     Milk
Baked Cauliflower       |     Lactose
Baked Salmon            |     NULL
Baked Salmon            |     Milk
Baked Salmon            |     Lactose
```

Now, what I would like to do, is to make a list of all dishes where any of the allergy names for a specific dish is not 'Egg', or etc.

For example, if I wanted to only get dishes that someone who could not eat Egg was, then I would run this query and should get back the dishes of `Avocado Chocolate Cream, Bacon Wrapped Asparagus, Baked Cauliflower and Baked Salmon`.

I have tried to set up some WHERE NOT IN, and other similar ones, but I continue to only remove a certain ingredient from the dish instead of just not selecting the dish. For example, in my attempted queries, with the 'Egg' example, Apple Cake would simply still return, but the specific row of 'Egg' would now not show.

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY` with no aggregate functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, think about how to determine which dishes have "Egg" in them.

```
SELECT
   FoodAllergyTbl.dish_id 
FROM
    `meals_food_allergytypes` AS FoodAllergyTbl
INNER JOIN
    `meals_allergytypes` AS AllergyTbl
     ON FoodAllergyTbl.allergy_types_id = AllergyTbl.id
WHERE
    AllergyTbl.name = 'Egg';
```

Then you can select the list of dishes where the `id` isn't in the above listing.

```
SELECT
    name
FROM
    `meal_dish`
WHERE
    `id` NOT IN (
    SELECT
       FoodAllergyTbl.dish_id 
    FROM
        `meals_food_allergytypes` AS FoodAllergyTbl
    INNER JOIN
        `meals_allergytypes` AS AllergyTbl
         ON FoodAllergyTbl.allergy_types_id = AllergyTbl.id
    WHERE
        AllergyTbl.name = 'Egg'
);
```

Comment: I didn't provide my table structure in the question fully, as to try and keep the main idea in focus. But I think your logic make sense, and am working towards reworking the queries slightly. I'll let you know!

Comment: Ok...well I really tried to get something like this working before posting this question, but couldn't get it. Nonetheless...I was able to rework it just a little to my information I didn't provide you and it was good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could use NOT  IN this way  for Dish Name  eg  for Egg:

```
  select name 
  from meals_dish
  where  name not in (
  SELECT distinct d.name     
  FROM meals_dish d
  JOIN meals_dishingredient di ON di.dish_id = d.id
  LEFT JOIN meals_food_allergytypes fat ON fat.food_id = di.food_id
  LEFT JOIN meals_allergytypes alt ON alt.id = fat.allergytypes_id 
             AND alt .AllergyName = 'Egg'
  )
```

Comment: Hmm...I have tried this one...but I am ending up with 0 dishes. I had to rename AllergyName to be alt.name at the end, because in your example it was no longer being named elsewhere. I'll keep thinking about the distinct option though...that could be on the right track

Comment: then  update your question add  a proper data sample  (not only your select) result and the related  expected  result   ... any way check better  because in only using not in your result with egg....